# PyTorch - Multiply 1D tensor across dimension 0 of 5D tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

So I have this tensor `A` that is `1`-dimensional of length `6` then I have another tensor `B` that's `5`-dimensional and dimension `0` is of shape `(6, batch size, 3, 100, 100)` . I'm trying to multiply all values in `B[n,:]` (`4`-dimensional tensor of shape `(batch size, 3, 100, 100)`) by the scalar `A[n]` where n is between `0` and `5`. How can I do this? The operation should also be differentiable because `A` comes out of a neural network and the `5`-dimensional tensor after this operation goes into another neural network which I'd like to backpropagate on fully.

I've tried this

```
inputs = A.view(6, 1, 1, 1, 1) * B
```

But it doesn't seem like the gradient flows through the neural network that outputs `A`.

Comment: the product looks right. check in the network that produces `A` for gradient issues.

Comment: @Shai how do I check that? I've been trying to find a way to check it.